# Is Grid System broken?

Tags: material-design-lite

I use mdl 1.1.3 from the cdn for a demo project. My layout is

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-phone">div1</div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-phone">div2</div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-phone">div3</div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-phone">div4</div>
</div>
```

mdl @media queries gives me a 75% of the parent div for the 6-col-cell.

@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width:839px)

- .mdl-cell--1-col  at 12.5%
- .mdl-cell--2-col  at 25%
- .mdl-cell--3-col  at 37.5%
- .mdl-cell--4-col  at 50% when it should be 25%
- .mdl-cell--5-col  at 62.5%
- .mdl-cell--6-col  at 75% when it should be 50%
- .mdl-cell--7-col  at 87.5%
- .mdl-cell--8-col  at 100%
- .mdl-cell--9-col  at 100%
- .mdl-cell--10-col at 100%
- .mdl-cell--11-col at 100%
- .mdl-cell--12-col at 100%

Is mdl fault or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

MDL site gave the answer.MDL has a different approach for grid system than other css frameworks. The number of maximum cells is deferent for different screen sizes.

- 12 cells for desktop screens
- 8 cells for tablets
- 4 cells for phones

that said for a simple layout like the one above we have to code it like this

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-phone">div1</div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-phone">div2</div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-phone">div3</div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-phone">div4</div>
</div>
```